# How to get personal group connect with other group without admin role

Tags: google-api, issue-tracking, usergroups, google-groups-api

Is there any API available like I write a single personal account email address and I get the all connected user groups?

For more clarification,
User "A" has A@gmail.com
and how to get the A@gmail.com user connected with other groups like Team@gmail.com without "Admin Role".

If an API is available can you please share the links or information?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid this is not possible. There is no specific API for Google Groups. This is limited to the [methods](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/groups) from the Admin SDK API where you can use the API to manage and check the groups from Google Workspace users.